# Push all images paths in an array of a whole website

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get the list of all images paths in an array used in my whole website?

```
var allImages = ['images/path1.jpg','images/path2.jpg','images/path3.png']
```

Comment: No, unless you do it server side. Why do you want to do this? Unless you mean on that specific page, you can't get all images.

Comment: @Vohuman I'm crazy to see that.

Comment: Do you want to get all images there are on your domain or just the images on a specific page?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, write a simple JS crawler, it's not that simple to write though.

Comment: If you want to get all images on your site, including those possibly hosted on other servers, short of hard coding all the paths you would need to use a web crawler that scrapes your entire site and pulls all the image paths. This would be quite time consuming for on-page processing so would be better served as an offline job that ran and then stored the values to a cache or DB

Comment: @Jonathan No, just images on my server only.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal then why not just use AJAX to get a list from your server? You could simple run a script that gets a list of all files in your images directory and returns them as an array. Still potentially expensive but doable

Comment: @JonathanCrowe could you please add an answer which would push all the images paths not only of the images folder but elsewhere in the website

Comment: That would depend entirely on your infrastructure, file structure, server-side language, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to get the images on the page at any given time, you could use [`document.images`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.images) to get the current images on the page, and then map over them to get the urls:

```
Array.prototype.map.call(document.images, function (image) { 
    return image.src;
});
```

Comment: "Is it possible to get the list of all images paths in an array used **in my whole website**?"

Comment: @northkildonan where does he say that his website isn't just a single page, or a SPA?

Comment: And for getting images of other pages, create an iframe dynamically and load the other pages in it. Or use PhantomJS.

Comment: @phenomnomnominal well, why would s/he use the term "whole website" then?

Comment: @northkildonan because if it is just one page, that one page would encompass the "whole website".

Comment: @phenomnomnominal then s/he would use the term "whole webpage"